# Geodesic Equations Surface Revolution Confusion

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic, submanifold

I'm using *Differential Geometry* by Tu and we are asked to find the Geodesic equations for a surface of revolution then prove the geodesics are Meridians. Though this question has appeared many times on this site, the form given for the geodesic equations don't seem to match what I get. I obtain the results [here](https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/course_builder/2223/math4030/14-Geodesic-3-beam-r-2022.pdf) for my geodesic equations, and they say that as a corollary, Meridians are geodesics and a parallel is a geodesic iff $f'(v_0) = 0$. My question is:
*How does the corollary follow from the Geodesic equations in this form?*

The $f'f''+g'g''$ term is tripping me up.
[image: Problem Statement]

...(derivation)

[image: Geodesic Equations and Statement of Corollary]

Comment: How is the term $f'f''+g'g''$ bothering you? What did you try?

Comment: A meridian has constant $u$ so that $\dot{u}$ and $\ddot{u}$ are equal to 0. So the first geodesic equation is automatically satisfied but the second geodesic equation becomes $\ddot{v} + \frac{f'f''+g'g''}{(f')^2+(g')^2} (\dot{v})^2 = 0$, and I'm not sure why this equation is satisfied, mainly because of the $f'f''+g'g''$ term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $f' = \frac{df}{dv}$, $g' = \frac{dg}{dv}$ and similar for $f'', g''$. Hence (note that $v = v(t)$)

\begin{split} 
f' f'' + g'g'' &= \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dv}\big( (f')^2 + (g')^2\big) \\
\end{split}
Hence
$$\frac{d}{dv} \sqrt{(f')^2 + (g')^2} = \frac{f'f'' + g'g''}{\sqrt{(f')^2 + (g')^2}}$$
Hence the geodesic equation becomes (write $\ell(t) = \sqrt{(f')^2 + (g')^2}$)

$$ \ell (t) \ddot v(t) + \dot \ell(t) \dot v(t) = 0,$$
or
$$ \ell (t) \dot v(t) = C.$$

Write $\ell (t) = \ell(v(t))$ (that is, $\ell(v) = \sqrt{(f'(v))^2 + (g'(v))^2}$), then

$$ t'(v) = \frac{C}{v'(t)} = \frac{C}{\ell(v)}$$
and one can integrate this to obtain $t(v)$, and hence $v(t)$.

**Remark** of course the above looks familiar: this is the ODE that you solve when you want to find an arc-length parametrization of a curve $\gamma(v) = (f(v), g(v))$. Indeed, since the surface of revolution (as a set) is the same when we reparametrize $(f(v), g(v))$, we may WLOG assume that $\gamma(v)$ is of arc-lenght parametrization to start with, so

$$ 1=|\gamma'(v)| = \sqrt{(f')^2 + (g')^2}.$$
So the geodesic equations becomes

\begin{split}
\ddot u + \frac{2f'}{f} \dot u\dot v &=0, \\
\ddot v - ff' (\dot u)^2 &= 0 
\end{split}

and when it is clear that $(u, v) = (u_0, at+b)$ are solutions to the geodesic equations.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see that simplification. Indeed, in the original problem given in Tu, the assumption is that the curve $\gamma$ is an arc-length parametrization. Now I see that I had overlooked the simplification that for an arc length parametrization, $f'f''+g'g'' = 0$.